# OpenLdap error: Your attempt to add uidNumber (2276) to <cn ....> is NOT allowed. That attribute/value belongs to another entry

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm using OpenLDAP. The management interface is `phpLDAPadmin`. Whilst this has made things easy, it also means I've not been exposed to the internals.

There is an existing entry using the `uidNumber 2276`.

In LDAP, I'm trying to create a new object using an existing template. This object is an email user. The template does not permit me to modify the `uidNumber`; it automatically tries to assign `uidNumber 2276` to the object. So, I can't add any more email users.

The existing entry looks like this:

```
icon    cn=UID Pool
    dn  cn=UID Pool,ou=server admin,dc= group
    cn  UID Pool
    objectClass uidPool
top
    gidNumber   1126
    uidNumber   2276
```

I'm not sure how to get around this. I'd really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was: I was logged in as the wrong user.

I'm tempted to delete the question